# How to paint world map with some data?

Tags: dataset, geography, geographics

I have a dataset which associate each country to respective number, from a list with few countries, as shown below:

```
data={{2705423, "United States"}, {2118645, "China"}, {817134, 
  "Germany"}, {729343, "United Kingdom"}, {704522, "Japan"}, {605133, 
  "India"}, {538269, "France"}, {461010, "Italy"}, {413584, 
  "Canada"}, {389763, "Russian Federation"}, {336262, 
  "South Korea"}, {322491, "Spain"}, {302802, "Australia"}, {222126, 
  "Brazil"}, {212629, "Netherlands"}, {203047, 
  "Switzerland"}, {193764, "Iran"}, {192998, "Poland"}, {177421, 
  "Sweden"}, {159057, "Taiwan"}, {128128, "Turkey"}, {123813, 
  "Belgium"}, {112496, "Denmark"}, {105011, "Malaysia"}, {97200, 
  "Austria"}}
```

I would like to print, in color scale, the corresponding country to their number.

I would like to paint, in color scale, each country to their respective number, as shown in the examples below

[image]

[image]

I thought of building the code from

```
GeoGraphics[{EdgeForm[Gray], 
  Tooltip[Polygon[GeoVariant[#, "SimplifiedArea"]], CommonName[#]] & /@
    CountryData[]}, GeoBackground -> None]
```

But I couldn't move forward.

Can anybody help me?

P.s.: I have other lists of other countries and other numbers.

Answer (score 5):

```
$Version

(* "13.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

data = {{2705423, "United States"}, {2118645, "China"}, {817134, 
    "Germany"}, {729343, "United Kingdom"}, {704522, 
    "Japan"}, {605133, "India"}, {538269, "France"}, {461010, 
    "Italy"}, {413584, "Canada"}, {389763, 
    "Russian Federation"}, {336262, "South Korea"}, {322491, 
    "Spain"}, {302802, "Australia"}, {222126, "Brazil"}, {212629, 
    "Netherlands"}, {203047, "Switzerland"}, {193764, 
    "Iran"}, {192998, "Poland"}, {177421, "Sweden"}, {159057, 
    "Taiwan"}, {128128, "Turkey"}, {123813, "Belgium"}, {112496, 
    "Denmark"}, {105011, "Malaysia"}, {97200, "Austria"}};
```

**EDIT:** Added `Tooltip`

```
GeoRegionValuePlot[(Tooltip[#[[2]], #[[1]]] -> #[[1]]) & /@
  (data /. str_String :> SemanticInterpretation[str])]
```

[image]